# Git Commit sublime message from Cygwin

Tags: python, git, github, cygwin, sublimetext3

I setup sublime text 3 to be my editor for git commit messages. 
I'm working on a PC (Windows 10) and use cygwin to run git through command line.

Perhaps this is the wrong way to use cygwin, but I'm working with git controlled files on my windows directory through cygwin (/cygdrive/c/users....)

When I go to commit, sublime text 3 pops up (application is saved in my program files directory), but I cannot save and close my message because the file path is not found

[image: Saving Error when finishing commit]
[image: cygwin interface]

I tried manually saving it to the .git file directory, which allows me to save it (via overwriting existing file) but when returning to cygwin,it says 'Aborting commit due to empty message'

Is there a way around this so I can use sublime text 3 as my editor and git from cygwin while managing windows folders?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text installed on Windows can't use the cygwin paths out of the box.

You may need some wrapper script which would translate the cygwin paths to the Windows paths for Sublime Text.
It could use the [cygpath](https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html) to do it.

Something like this:

`git config --global core.editor /path/to/editor_wrapper.sh`

**editor_wrapper.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
/cygdrive/c/.../path/to/sublime_text $(cygpath -w "$1")
```

*Note:
I believe it's not the only way, but it clearly shows the approach.*

Comment: So you create a .sh file to handle the cygwin path (using cygpath... will have to look into that). In which directory would you place the editor_wrapper.sh file?

Comment: Whatever's accessible to cygwin e.g. `~/editor_wrapper.sh`

Comment: Thanks! Revisited issue... no luck. I opened VI in root (~) and made the editor_wrapper.sh file with the sublime text 3 directory path (C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3). Ran git config, then commit and received the following error: **error:** cannot run editor_wrapper.sh: No such file or directory. **error:** unable to start editor 'editor_wrapper.sh' Tried creating this file in my git repository, also checked the one in my root folder. I did run git config exactly as you typed it above (git config --global core.editor editor_wrapper.sh). Tried git config using 'subl' instead of core.editor..

Comment: Hey. I've just edited the answer to make it more readable that you should provide a full path to the wrapper as well. E.g. `git config --global core.editor ~/editor_wrapper.sh`